# TFS 2013, GitTemplate12 with MSBuild 14.0

Tags: c#, msbuild

I just built a Windows 2012R server as our build server.

The following are installed:

- VS2012 with latest update
- VS2013 with latest update
- VS2015 with latest update
- TFS 2013 with no update and configured the Build Service

We are using GIT in TFS 2013 so the Build Process Template is **GitTemplate12.xml**.

The following attempts have been made to change the controller to use MSBuild14.0 instead of MSBuild12.0 during build, with no success

- add **/tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0** to the MSBuild Parameters in build process definition
- Use VS2013 designer to change the **ToolVersion** of **RunMSBuild** activity to **"14.0"** in GitTemplate12.xml and change the build process to use it

Any ideas what might be the issues? Seen other people make it work with TFS template. Feel I am running out of possible solutions.

The diagnostics step log for Run MS Build at beginning shows

> Inputs  ProjectsToBuild: String[] Array  MSBuildMultiProc: True 
>   Verbosity: Normal  ToolPlatform: Auto  Targets:   RunCodeAnalysis:
>   AsConfigured  CommandLineArguments: /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
>   /tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 ,

but the following logs for the build still shows 12.0

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\nuget.exe
>   restore "D:\Builds\11\abc.sln" -NonInteractive
>
> All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>
> **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64**\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "D:\Builds\11\abc.sln"

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on TFS 2013.5 with default GitTemplate12.xml build template, and just add `/tv:14.0` to the msbuild arguments in build template, then the build use MSBuild 14.0 as expected.

[image]

In order to figurate out why it didn't work on your side. Try the items below:

1. Create a light project and use the default GitTemplate12.xml build template to have a test.
2. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`.
3. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data`.